# first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: trigger, dmlexception

i have a custom object called work order. today one of our business user tried to create a work order record it is giving me the following error.

Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger sm1e.WorkOrderTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: sm1e.WorkOrderTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0T0n00000005SFEAY; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 0010n000002HIzY: []: (sm1e)

I am System administrator and when try to reproduce the issue, i dint see anything wrong. I successfully created the record.

What permissions do i need to check?

The trigger related to the record is below:

trigger WorkOrderTrigger on sm1e__smWork_Order__c (before update) {

```
WorkOrderHelper.validateWorkOrderStatus(Trigger.newMap);
```

}

The helper class that is called by the trigger is:

public class WorkOrderHelper{

```
public static void validateWorkOrderStatus(Map<Id, sm1e__smWork_Order__c> orderMap){
    System.debug('Indide validateWorkOrderStatus');
    String C_NEW = 'New';
    String CANCELED = 'Canceled';
    String COMPLETED = 'Completed'; 
    String SCHEDULE_CONFIRMED = 'Schedule Confirmed';       

    Set<Id> workOrderIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> assignmentIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> entitlementIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<String> statusSet = new Set<String>{C_NEW, CANCELED, COMPLETED, SCHEDULE_CONFIRMED};

    Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_A__c> entitlementMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_A__c>();
    List<sm1e__WO_Assignment__c> updatedWorkAssignmentList = new List< sm1e__WO_Assignment__c>();

    for(sm1e__smWork_Order__c order : orderMap.values()){
        if(order.Entitlement_Name__c != null)
           entitlementIdSet.add(order.Entitlement_Name__c);
    }

    entitlementMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_A__c>([SELECT Id, 
                                                               Term__c,
                                                               Term_Units__c,  
                                                               End_Date__c,
                                                               Beginning_Date__c  
                                                        FROM sm1e__smCObject_A__c 
                                                        WHERE Id IN: entitlementIdSet]);

    for(sm1e__smWork_Order__c order : orderMap.values()){
        if(entitlementMap != null && entitlementMap.containsKey(order.Entitlement_Name__c)){
            sm1e__smCObject_A__c entitlement = entitlementMap.get(order.Entitlement_Name__c);
            if(!evaluateEntitlementStatus(entitlement.Term__c, entitlement.Term_Units__c, entitlement.Beginning_Date__c)){
               order.addError('Work order cannot be updated, since Entitlement of this work order is not active.');
               return;
            }    
        }

        if(order.sm1e__Status__c == COMPLETED){
            workOrderIdSet.add(order.Id);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, sm1e__smWork_Order__c> workOrderMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smWork_Order__c>([SELECT Id, 
                                                                                             sm1e__Status__c, 
                                                                                             (SELECT Id, 
                                                                                                     sm1e__Assignment_Status__c 
                                                                                              FROM sm1e__WO_Assignments__r) 
                                                                                      FROM sm1e__smWork_Order__c         
                                                                                      WHERE Id IN: workOrderIdSet]);

    for(Id workOrderId : orderMap.keySet()){
       if(workOrderMap.containsKey(workOrderId) && workOrderMap.get(workOrderId).sm1e__WO_Assignments__r != null){
          for(sm1e__WO_Assignment__c  assignment : workOrderMap.get(workOrderId).sm1e__WO_Assignments__r){   
             if(!statusSet.contains(assignment.sm1e__Assignment_Status__c)){
                 orderMap.get(workOrderId).addError('This work order still has assignments that are accruing time. The work order cannot be Completed until these assignments are complete and no longer accruing time.');
             }
             if(assignment.sm1e__Assignment_Status__c == C_NEW 
                || assignment.sm1e__Assignment_Status__c == SCHEDULE_CONFIRMED){
                assignmentIdSet.add(assignment.Id);
             }
          }
       } 
    }  

    if(assignmentIdSet != null && !assignmentIdSet.isEmpty()){
       updatedWorkAssignmentList = [SELECT Id, 
                                           sm1e__Assignment_Status__c 
                                    FROM sm1e__WO_Assignment__c
                                    WHERE Id IN: assignmentIdSet]; 

       if(updatedWorkAssignmentList != null && !updatedWorkAssignmentList.isEmpty()){
          for(sm1e__WO_Assignment__c assignment : updatedWorkAssignmentList){
            assignment.sm1e__Assignment_Status__c = CANCELED;
          }

          update updatedWorkAssignmentList;
       }                            
    }               
}

public static void validateEntitlementStatus(List<sm1e__smWork_Order__c> orderList){
    Set<Id> entitlementIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_A__c> entitlementMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_A__c>();

    for(sm1e__smWork_Order__c order : orderList){
        if(order.Entitlement_Name__c != null)
           entitlementIdSet.add(order.Entitlement_Name__c);
    }

    entitlementMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smCObject_A__c>([SELECT Id, 
                                                               Term__c,
                                                               Term_Units__c,  
                                                               End_Date__c,
                                                               Beginning_Date__c   
                                                        FROM sm1e__smCObject_A__c 
                                                        WHERE Id IN: entitlementIdSet]);

    for(sm1e__smWork_Order__c order : orderList){
        if(order.Entitlement_Term__c != null && entitlementMap != null && entitlementMap.containsKey(order.Entitlement_Name__c)){
            sm1e__smCObject_A__c entitlement = entitlementMap.get(order.Entitlement_Name__c);
            if(!evaluateEntitlementStatus(entitlement.Term__c, entitlement.Term_Units__c, entitlement.Beginning_Date__c)){
               order.addError('Work order cannot be created, since Entitlement of this work order is not active.');
               return;
            }    
        }
    }    
}

private static boolean evaluateEntitlementStatus(Decimal term, String termUnits, Date beginningDate){
    Date endDate;
    boolean flag = false;
    Integer iTerm;
    if(term == null)
       iTerm = 0;
    else
       iTerm = Integer.valueOf(term);
    System.debug('iTerm: '+iTerm);
    System.debug('termUnits: '+termUnits);      
    if(beginningDate != null && termUnits != null){
        if(termUnits.equalsIgnoreCase('days')){
           System.debug('Inside days');
           endDate =  beginningDate.addDays(iTerm);
           System.debug('endDate: '+endDate);
        }else if(termUnits.equalsIgnoreCase('weeks')){
           Integer noOfDays = iTerm * 7;
           endDate =  beginningDate.addDays(iTerm);
        }else if(termUnits.equalsIgnoreCase('months')){
           endDate =  beginningDate.addMonths(iTerm);
        }else if(termUnits.equalsIgnoreCase('years')){
           endDate =  beginningDate.addYears(iTerm);
        }
        if(endDate != null && endDate >= Date.today())
           flag = true;     
    }
    System.debug('flag : '+flag);
    return flag;    
}
```

}

I checked the object and field permissions. Everything looked fine. But I don't understand why i'm getting this error.

Comment: Check all parent and child objects referenced with Workorder

Comment: there are more than 20 object relations with work order. so the logged in user who is getting error should have access to all those objects. Is this what you are saying?